# How to find overlapping connected components

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, overlay

I have two separate images: the first image only contains the black round objects, while the second image only contains the green round objects. I am trying to make a code that will figure out how much of the green is in the black objects. There are three different scenarios that could happen when overlaying image 1 (image with black objects only) and image 2 (image with green objects only) as shown in the image below.

[image]

I have tried to extract the pixel indices of the black and green objects using `regionprops` and check whether if there are any overlapping pixels using `ismember`. Each cell contains the pixel indices of the a single object. I feel that there is something I'm doing wrong in the code but I can't seem to grasp what it is exactly. I'm sure that there is a simpler method to do this.

```
blackProperties = regionprops(logical(blackImage),'all');
greenProperties = regionprops(logical(greenImage),'all');
numBlackObjects = length(blackProperties);
numGreenObjects = length(greenProperties);
blackPixels = cell(1,numBlackObjects);
greenPixels = cell(1,numGreenObjects);

for j = 1:numBlackObjects
    blackPixels{j} = blackProperties(j).PixelIdxList;
end

for j = 1:numGreenObjects
    greenPixels{j} = greenProperties(j).PixelIdxList;
end

matchMem = zeros(100,2);

for j = 1:numel(blackPixels)
    blackPix = blackPixels{j};
    for i = 1:numel(greenPixels)
        greenPix = greenPixels{i};
        match = ismember(blackPix,greenPix);
        matchMem(match,1) = find(match);
        matchMem(match,2) = i;
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that uses `regionprops` to get `blackPixels` and `greenPixels`? You can easily solve this with boolean logic.

Comment: your images have the same size ?

Comment: @Suever, I have edited the question

Comment: @obchardon, Yes the two images are of the same size

Comment: @Senyokbalgul YOu didn't show where you call `regionprops`.

Comment: @Suever, Oh sorry I've edited the question again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do a logical AND (`&`) with the green and black images which will tell you where they overlap. Then if you need connected components, you can call `regionprops` on the resulting overlap image.

```
green_and_black = blackImage & greenImage;
overlap_props = regionprops(green_and_black, 'all')
```